# Does deactivating and reactivating the SharePoint Publishing features cause data loss?

Tags: 2010, publishing, content

In a SharePoint 2010 Site Collection and in its Subsites the [SharePoint Publishing Features](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628963%28v=office.14%29.aspx) are enabled:

1. SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure Feature (Site Collection Level)
2. SharePoint Server Publishing Feature (Site Level)

The content database(s) were migrated from another environment to the current environment.

Now I've got the impression something is wrong with the SharePoint Publishing Features and a suggested option is re-provisioning the SharePoint Publishing Features.

I was wondering if deactivating the [SharePoint Publishing Features](http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/06/23/sharepoint-publishing-features-functionality.aspx) and afterwards reactivating the SharePoint Publishing Features would cause any data loss to the environment.

1. What happens to the Sites, Document Libraries, Content Types that were created by the SharePoint Publishing Features? Will they be deleted by deactivating the Publishing Features?
2. What will happen to the the sites, document libraries, content types, master pages if customizations were made?
3. What will happen to the Sites, Document Libraries, Content Types, Content, ... when reactivating the Publishing Features? Will they be overwritten by reactivating the Publishing Features?
4. Will creating a backup of the content database(s) provide a sufficient fallback option if data loss is a risk?

Are there users here that have experience in deactivating and reactivating the SharePoint Publishing Features when something is amiss?

In short: Does deactivating and reactivating the SharePoint Publishing features cause data loss to existing sites, content, document libraries, content types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no data loss associated with deactivating/activating this feature.

Comment: So content types, libraries, sites that were customized with different settings as default will not be removed or reset to default after deactivating and then reactivating the Publishing Features?

Comment: That's correct. We've used disable/enable as a troubleshooting step with Publishing.

Comment: I created a content database backup and disabled the SharePoint Publishing Features. Nothing seemed to be broken by disabling the feature. However my issue was not solved by re-enabling the Features, thus i restored the backup i created of my content database.